# How to trigger in-app navigation based on API response

Tags: android, ios, swift

This question relates to both ios (swift) and android.

I'm working on building the backend implementation for a banner system that our mobile apps need to integrate with. Some of the banners need to redirect a user to a section of the app when pressed.

What is the best practice for triggering route navigation based on data returned in an API call?

For example, a list of banner objects in JSON where a key references the page to navigate to - would deep linking apply here, does it make sense for the apps to create a mapping of routes that I can reference by passing a string?

I feel like there has to be a simple solution here but the mobile team I'm working with seems pretty adamant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current project (iOS), we are using deep links to map navigation to a certain tab of our app. So you could send it through JSON and then post a Notification, which your main controller is listening to (TabBarController for example), and then select the wanted index to go to, or any other navigation logic you need.

// Registering the deeplink with DeepLinkKit pod (https://github.com/button/DeepLinkKit)

```
    self.router?.register("a/created/path") { link in
                if let link = link {
                    debugPrint("Router: \(String(describing: link.url))")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(
                        name: Notification.Name(Configuration.App.kGoToSomewhere),
                        object: nil
                    )
                }
            }
```

Or just extracted from your JSON and then setup the notification

```
    call { URL in
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
                            name:   Notification.Name("ANotification"),
                            object: nil
                        )
    }
```

And then in your main controller

```
    class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
       func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
          NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(selectTab),
                name: Notification.Name("ANotificaton"),
                object: nil
            )
    }
    }

func selectTab() {
 // Do your navigation logic here
}
```

I hope it helps!